# Ultracapacitor, capacitance higher than rated?

Tags: measurement, capacitance, supercapacitor, equation

Broadening my knowledge and experience about ultracapacitors I've made a test bench that was described in [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444943/ultracapacitor-initial-voltage-drop-during-discharging).
I've used an IEC methodology to calculate the capacitance:
$$
C = (I_d*t_d) / (\Delta U)
$$
where delta U is difference of voltages equal to:
$$
\Delta U = 0.9 *U_r -0.7 * Ur
$$
where Ur is a rated voltage equal to 2,75 V
Other values that I've measured are:

- td = 202 s
- Id = 10 A

My calculation predicts C to be ~3600 F. Whereas rated capacitance of ultracapacitor is 3000 F. Are my calculations wrong or the calculated capacitance is a maximal capacitance available to achieve for this ultracap, but manufacturer limits it to 3000 F? Or assures only the 3000 F?

Comment: What's the tolerance on the capacitor? Electrolytics and double-layer capacitors tend to have really wide tolerances.

Comment: Product matrix doesn't show the capacitance tolerance. It is BCAP3000F with Ur = 2,75 Volts. I've searched in the Internet and found it to be -10/+20 %
This site provides the info about ultracapacitor tolerance: https://picclick.com/Maxwell-BCAP3000-Boostcap-Ultracapacitor-Capacitor-3000f-27v-Lot-263304774762.html

Comment: https://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/K2Series_DS_1015370_5_20141104.pdf indicates the minimum value is 3000, and the maximum is 3600, so the tolerance is all to the positive side.

Comment: I think this answers my question. Topic to close.

Comment: I'll put this as an answer then so you can close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Energy storage devices usually are  toleranced to ensure that a minimum value is met.

For this cap, the [datasheet](http://maxwell.com/images/documents/K2Series_DS_1015370_5_20141104.pdf) indicates the minimum value is 3000F, and the maximum is 3600F, so the tolerance is all to the positive side.

Answer (score 2):

3600F is the start capacitance and 0.29 mΩ is the initial ESR.

**3000F** is the rated C after certain conditions.

a. -20 % after 1500 hours  held continuously at Rated Voltage and Maximum Operating Temperature 65'C
or ...

b. -20 % after 10 years held continuously at Rated Voltage but at 25'C 
or ...

c. -20 % after 1,000,000 cycles at 25'C

These reductions are cumulative.

Also same is given for ESR , which can double (2x) or rise 100%.

Always [Read The (OEM's) Fine Print](https://www.maxwell.com/images/documents/K2Series_DS_1015370_5_20141104.pdf)

Don't assume the Distributor has valid specs.
e.g. [Your link](https://picclick.com/Maxwell-BCAP3000-Boostcap-Ultracapacitor-Capacitor-3000f-27v-Lot-263304774762.html) Ultracapacitor Cell Capacitance: 3000.0 F -10/+20%

the **.0** should give it away to you, that Caps do not have 5 significant Figures.